# c# read/extract transparent icons from external applications?

Tags: c#, icons, size, transparent

this is a tricky question

I need to look into an app get the number of icons and the sizes
1-extract the icon(s) with keeping the transparent info
2-so when I show it on a winform it will be with no colored background?

so the alpha-channel in the icon is needed

any solution that cover both or any of the question will be really help full

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Windows API Resource Functions through pinvoke calls, here is a list of the functions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468902(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, any specific one to use, or I should read them all ;-), any ways there is a handful list :-) cheers

Comment: You'd need to LoadLibraryEx the target, enum the resources of RC_ICON or something and pull the raw icon data or load it as a HICON, I don't recall the exact process haven't done this in quite a while :)